# Does Lotus domino 9 supports lotus notes adapter 5.1 ？

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, tivoli-identity-manager

Recently someone upgrades his lotus domino from version 7 to version 9, while I find the lotus notes adapter 5.1 which I use doesn't work. Does lotus domino 9 supports lotus notes adapter 5.1 ?

I cannot find any useful information with google.

Comment: what is tim5.1?

Comment: sorry. That means lotus notes adapter 5.1

Comment: I think you question should be "Does the IBM Tivoli Identity Manager" support Notes/Domino 9

Comment: We have an IBM Tivoli Identity Manager 5.1, which cannot be replaced right now. That's my dilemma. @ThomasAdrian